# How to give a .php file unique name at top of page, and display unique name on index.php file

Tags: php, string, variables, directory

I have a question and it's probably a simple one.  What I would like to do is be able to place a unique name at the top of each .php file in a folder in the php code  area.  I would then like a script on the index.php file to look in that folder, pull out the unique names of each .php file found at the top of each page in the php code, and display them in a list on the index.php page.

Would I have to do something like this at the top of the page:

```
< ?
{{{{{uniquenamehere}}}}}
? >
```

And If so, what would the code look like for grabbing uniquenamehere and displaying in on the index.php page?

Thanks in advance, let me know if I need to be any more clear in my question.  Sorry if it's a really simple question, I'm stumped!

EDIT

Getting this warning when using answer below:
Warning: file_get_contents(test.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/index.php

Here's the code I am using,

```
  <?php

// Scan directory for files
$dir = "path/";
$files = scandir($dir);

// Iterate through the list of files 
foreach($files as $file)
{
// Determine info about the file
$parts = pathinfo($file);

// If the file extension == php
if ( $parts['extension'] === "php" )
{
// Read the contents of the file
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// Find first occurrence of opening template tag
$from = strpos($contents, "{{{{{");

// Find first occurrence of ending template tag
$to = strpos($contents,"}}}}}");

// Pull out the unique name from between the template tags
$uniqueName = substr($contents, $from+5, $to);

// Print out the unique name
echo $uniqueName ."<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can't you just use the file names? What you want is possible but seems like a messy approach...

Comment: Give an example "unique name", or a few examples. *edit:* and what does MySQL have to do with it?

Comment: I agree with @DaveRandom, just use file names.  It would be much easier than opening and reading each file.

Comment: This approach is not at all unheard of. CMS's like Wordpress do this exact type of approach. The names of template files are defined at the top of each PHP file in a specific format. Wordpress then parses the list of files and pulls out the template names. Also, the `uniquename` KGDD might want to use could contain characters that are not appropriate or acceptable for use in filenames as well.

Comment: Or use the `<title>` tags; I've done this when creating my own directory listing for stubborn hosts without .htaccess. But this is sloooow compared to using the filenames.

Comment: Jakobud's code worked but I am getting the error message in the comment on this answer, anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but it should be roughly something like this.

```
<?php

// Scan directory for files
$fileInfo = pathinfo(__FILE__);

$dir = $fileInfo['dirname'];
$files = scandir($dir);

// Iterate through the list of files
foreach($files as file)
{
  // Determine info about the file
  $parts = pathinfo($file);

  // If the file extension == php
  if ( $parts['extension'] == "php" )
  {
    // Read the contents of the file
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);

    // Find first occurrenceof opening template tag
    $from = strpos($contents, "{{{{{");

    // Find first occurrenceof ending template tag
    $to = strpos($contents,"}}}}}");

    // Pull out the unique name from between the template tags
    $uniqueName = substr($contents, $from+5, $to);

    // Print out the unique name
    echo $uniqueName ."<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: It's finding the files in the directory, but is not pulling out the name between the {{{{{ }}}}}

Warning: file_get_contents(test.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/index.php

Comment: It sounds like your `$dir` path was not the same location as your index.php. I modified the above script to search the current directory of the script instead of an arbitrary directory.